# How to concatenate two arrays in Fortran 90

Tags: arrays, fortran, concatenation, fortran90

I have an original array called `pres_lev3d`,  whose size is defined by `pres_lev3d(im*jm, levsi)`, where `im*jm` is 72960 and `levsi` is 64. This corresponds to global atmospheric data, thus the size. The array is allocatable: `real (kind=kind_io8), allocatable :: pres_lev3d(:, :)`. I have a second array, `press_1d`, whose size is also defined in a similar fashion  `pres_1d(im*jm, levsi)`, but in this array `levsi` is 1.

I need to concatenate both arrays (technically a 2d and 1d array) to an array of the shape `(/72960, 65/)`. In MATLAB this seems like a very simple process, however, I can't seem to find an easy way to go around it in Fortran 90.

I have tried to create a third array

```
pres_lev=(/pres_lev3d, pres_1d/)
```

and also tried to use `merge`, but none of these approaches seem to work out.

I am fairly new to Fortran.

Answer (score 4):

If I've followed your explanation correctly this would probably work

```
   real(kind_io8), dimension(72960,65) :: out_array
   ...
   out_array(:,1:64) = pres_lev3d
   out_array(:,65) = pres_1d
```

If that's not easy enough, or if I've misunderstood your question, explain further.  To allocate `out_array` to conform to your input arrays, try something like

```
   real(kind_io8), dimension(:,:), allocatable :: out_array
   ...
   allocate(out_array(size(pres_lev3d,1),size(pres_lev3d,2)+1))
   ...
   out_array(:,1:64) = pres_lev3d
   out_array(:,65) = pres_1d
```